# HTML rendering using NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an HTML with base 64 encoded inline image. I have to display this in an application. I am using NSTextView to display this. Now this works fine in 10.6 but in 10.5 instead of the image I kind of see a placeholder. So I went ahead and tried opening that HTML with Text Edit. The same thing happened. TextEdit on 10.6 is able to render it perfectly but 10.5 TextEdit is just not able to render the image.

Can some one please tell me what could be wrong. The HTML is like -

```
<html>
<head>..</head>
<body><p>
<img width="213" height="123" src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/....."alt="" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: Please dont ask why I am not using WebView. I have to use NSTextView.

Comment: Have you tried with different inline images to see if it's a general problem or it's specific to your image?

Comment: I have tried with different inline images but the result is the same. It does not show up.